# Finding a "special" non singular submatrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, algorithms, determinants

Given a square integer matrix $A \in M_n(Z)$ and two subsets $I, J \subset \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$, we define $A_{I,J}$ as the sub-matrix of $A$ containing the rows (resp. columns) whose index is in $I$ (resp. $J$).

I wonder if there is a fast algorithm for finding maximal sets $I$ and $J$, $I \cap J = \emptyset$ such that $\det(A_{I,J}) = \pm 1$.

Note: Obviously, $I$ and $J$ have the same cardinal.

Comment: It seems unlikely that such sets $I,J$ even exists for any matrix $A\in M_n(\Bbb Z)$. Define $A_{i,j}=2$ for every $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then every sub-matrix $A_{I,J}$ is singular (and so $\det(A_{I,J})=0$) except when $|I|=|J|=n-1$, in which case $\det(A_{I,J})=\det(2)=2$... (and I did not mentioned the zero matrix...)

Comment: First, I consider $I$ and $J$ as the rows and columns that **do** appear in $A_{I,J}$. Thus, the maximal sets in your example are the empty ones.

Comment: Ok sorry, I misread your question. Also I did not notice that you require $I\cap J= \emptyset$